# Mongodb date field not setting date in local timezone

Tags: node.js, mongodb, momentjs

I am using Moment.js to set dates in Node.js server. Works fine but for some reason when creating a new model and assigning a date, the time is set two hours earlier.

```
const Comment = require('./../models/comment');
const moment = require('moment');
const { getAccessToken } = require('../services/jwt');

function createComment(req, res) {
    
    const comment = new Comment();

    const { user, content, post_slug, post_title, post_type , post_id, thumb } = req.body;

    comment.user = user;
    comment.content = content;
    comment.post_slug = post_slug;
    comment.post_id = post_id;
    comment.post_title = post_title;
    comment.post_type = post_type;
    comment.published_at = moment().format();
    comment.thumb = thumb;
    comment.deleted = false;

    console.log(comment.published_at); //2021-06-09T17:36:13.000Z
    console.log(moment().format()); //2021-06-09T19:36:13+02:00

    if (!user || !content || !post_id || !post_slug || !post_type || !post_title) {
        res.status(404).send({status: 404, message: "Ha habido un problema con la recepción de los datos."});
    } else {
        comment.save((err, commentStored) => {
            if (err) {
              res.status(500).send({message: "Error del servidor" + err})
            } else {
              if (!commentStored) {
                res.status(404).send({message: "Error al crear el comentario"});
              } else {
                res.status(200).send({comment: commentStored})
              }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Already set Time Zone in MongoDB settings:

```
console.log(comment.published_at); //2021-06-09T17:36:13.000Z
console.log(moment().format()); //2021-06-09T19:36:13+02:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Date values in MongoDB are always (and only) stored as UTC time. You need to display local times at your client side or store input time zone in a separate field.

And I think you should better use

```
comment.published_at = moment().toDate()
```